# Why do we use inline keyword on a variable in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, inline

What I can understand from google documentation is that we can use inline keyword to enhance the performance and reduce the memory allocation on runtime in case of high order function but why in this case we are inlining a variable

```
@PublishedApi
internal inline val <T : Any> T.loggingTag: String
    get() {
        val tag = this::class.java.name.substringAfterLast(".")
        if (tag.contains("$")) {
            return tag.substringBefore("$")
        }

        return tag
    }
```

in case you are curious the logging tag variable is used in an inline function

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.errorLog(error: Throwable? = null, message: String? = null) {
    errorLog(loggingTag, error, message)
}
```

also the errorLog function inlined even it doesn't take an other function as a parameters does anyone able to explain for me this ?

```
inline fun errorLog(tag: String, error: Throwable? = null, message: String? = null) {
    Timber.tag(tag).e(error, message)
}
```

Comment: "why in this case we are inlining a variable" -- `inline` applies to functions, not variables. In your first example, `inline` will apply to the `get()` function for that computed property.

Answer (score 1):

That `val` isn't a variable. It's a property. If you see `val` or `var` outside of a function, it's a property, not a variable.

Properties have getter functions. In your example, the getter function is what is being marked as `inline`.

There are two main reasons to use inline functions:

1. In a higher order function, it avoids allocating a function object to represent the function parameter (lambda or function reference) being passed to it. It also allows lambdas that are passed to use keywords that are normally restricted to local use, such as `return`, `break`, and `continue`.
2. It is necessary for reified generics. If a function needs to be able to inspect one of its generic types, the type needs to be marked as `reified`, which in turn requires the function to be marked `inline`.

Generally, you want to avoid using `inline` if a function doesn't fit one of the above cases, because actual function calls themselves are rather trivial, and if you inline a function that is used frequently (the only kind of function you would want to be optimized), then its code is going to be repeated everywhere it's used in your compiled app, increasing the size of the app.

An exception might be if the inline function contains only one function call, so it's not really increasing code size.

I do not see any reason the `inline` keyword is needed for the extension property in your first block of code. It is not a higher-order function, and it is a multi-line function. I also don't see why it is defined as a generic function, since the type `T` is not used for anything inside the function. I think I would define it as:

```
internal val Any.loggingTag: String
```

Also, in your second block of code, I don't see any reason why there is a generic type, since it is not used in that function. It could be defined as:

```
fun Any.errorLog(error: Throwable? = null, message: String? = null) {
```

The third block of code doesn't benefit much from inlining either. It's not a higher-order function. If function call overhead is that much of an issue for performance, it would make more sense to fork Timber and rewrite how it creates tags, because using custom temporary tags like that in Timber involves a few method calls under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was really helpful for me to understand what the developer wants to do, I agree regarding the reified stuff since we are not using the generic type it's just useless, but I think the reason why we was using the inline keyword everywhere in our functions that are not high order function is to avoid this performance issue that you talked about, since, if we call the errorLog it will be the same thing that if we called Timber directly.

Comment: I didn't talk about a performance issue. I said that function calls are generally trivial. They are likely inlined in modern JIT VMs, so in those cases, the inline function has no benefit and only serves to make the compiled app larger.